# Python Selenium - Error with using chrome profiles

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm trying to run selenium using chrome profiles.

Here's my code:

```
 PATH = "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
 options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\otter\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
 options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
 driver.get("www.youtube.com")
```

But when i run, it throws me this long error:

```
Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

Whats wrong? :(

I got the path and profile details from typing `chrome://version` in Google Chrome.

It's hard to find a good answer for this . Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you download the chromedriver.exe from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads ? Check your Chrome version and download the driver.

Comment: @June Um.. Yes. It's stated at the top of my code under `PATH`

Comment: @SeleniumUser002 That post didn't answered my question